# Handle exceptions when database doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm not familiar with exception handling (not much of a developer).

How do I catch an exception when a database doesn't exist or is offline? Do I need to throw a new Exception? The following gets me the warning "Exception was unhandled by user code"

```
catch (Exception err)
{
    if (err is OracleException)
    {
        //database does not exist?
        ErrorMessage = err.Message;
        throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage = err.Message;
        con.Close();
        throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);  
    }
```

Comment: If you are **throwing** it you need to catch it somewhere and then decide what you need to continue with.. Can you add more detail about the part of this code as in on what action this is been done?

Comment: The catch block is generally where you would "handle" an exception, usually by indicating to the user that an error has occured. It's generally considered bad practice to catch an exception, and then throw a new one as when you investigate the "unhandled" exception (the one your threw) there are no details such as the stack trace included.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you will generally be able to see what types of exception a method call might throw by hovering over the method name (eg SqlConnect) in your code. This should give you an idea of what types of exceptions to catch/handle.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao oh then perhaps I don't need to throw anything. I just want the function to connect to a database and, if that database doesn't exist, exit out of the function without crashing and have the webpage show nothing. If I don't include a throw statement, I get an error that all code paths must return a value so I assumed I had to throw something.

Comment: @rory_za Hovering doesn't seem to do anything. But when I run the code it gives me "An exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in DataLayer.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: External component has thrown an exception" I tried to catch the OracleException with the if statement but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Well you can just use `return` in that case instead of `throw`. Bdw, what's the return type your `function` has?

Comment: The purpose of catching is what function/method/message you want to do if an exception occurs that brings some kind of feedback and does not crash. Instead of a generic catch Exception and then trying to figure out what it is, I would go with a catch (OracleException ox) block and do something akin to saying "unable to connect to DB". You can have more than one catch block, the last of which would be the generic catch Exception

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the return type is List<CodeDesc> (a list of CodeDesc objects which I've defined).

Comment: Then just try with `return;`. That should be fine..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `return;` gives me a type error but `return null` works. Thanks!

Comment: Great.. or you could just do `return new List<CodeDesc>();` an empty list to be on safer side.. `return null;` will also be a good option.. No doubt..

Answer (score 0):

The 'Catch' expression is used to handle the Exception. If you are throwing another Exception, it needs to be catched somewhere.
And C# allows you to catch more than one exceptions, so you can do this:

```
try 
{ 
    //TRY TO OPEN THE CONNECTION
}
catch (OracleException oraExcep)
{
    //DO SOMETHING IF A OracleException
    //ERROR IS HANDLED HERE
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```